# Next.js Link prefetch provoke 404 errors in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a blog using Next.JS.
In this blog, I have a page where I present all of my articles.

The rendered component looks like this:

```js
<div>
    {articles.map((article, index) => {
        const path = `/magazine/${article.id}/${encodeURIComponent(
            article.formatted_name
        )}`;

        return (
            <Link key={article.id} href={path} as={path} prefetch>
                <a>
                    <CardArticle article={article} index={index} />
                </a>
            </Link>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

Links are working just fine and in development mode, there are no error at all.
However, after a build, the Links are still working just fine, but the prefetch from the Links fail when I'm on the page with the presented list of articles:

[image: 404 errors during prefetch]

Note if relevant: the list of articles if fetched using an API call in `getServerSideProps`.

Does anyone know why my `<Link>` fail to prefetch but still work otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you are using `href` and `as` incorrectly. As per the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link), href should be thy dynamic link in the pages directory (such as `/magazine/[id]/[name]` - change for your use case) and `as` is correct.

Comment: hi! I seem to have a similar problem. Could you take a look at it, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889063/next-js-link-prefetch-results-in-404-in-production